# EventHandler Implementation F#

Tags: c#, .net, f#, xamarin.ios, eventhandler

I am implementing the following `C#` code in `F#`:

```
    using Softweb.Xamarin.Controls.iOS;

public class DemoViewController : UIViewController, ICardViewDataSource
{

    public CardView DemoCardView { get; set; }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        DemoCardView = new CardView();

        //Wire up events
        DemoCardView.DidSwipeLeft += OnSwipe;
        DemoCardView.DidSwipeRight += OnSwipe;
        DemoCardView.DidCancelSwipe += OnSwipeCancelled;
        DemoCardView.DidStartSwipingCardAtLocation += OnSwipeStarted;
        DemoCardView.SwipingCardAtLocation += OnSwiping;
        DemoCardView.DidEndSwipingCard += OnSwipeEnded;
    }

    void OnSwipe(object sender, SwipeEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("View swiped.\n");
    }

    void OnSwipeCancelled(object sender, SwipeEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Swipe cancelled.\n");
    }

    void OnSwipeStarted(object sender, SwipingStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Started swiping at location {0}\n", e.Location);
    }

    void OnSwiping(object sender, SwipingEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Swiping at location {0}\n", e.Location);
    }

    void OnSwipeEnded(object sender, SwipingEndedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Ended swiping at location {0}\n", e.Location);
    }
}
```

I am not sure however how to replicate the

```
DemoCardView.DidSwipeLeft += OnSwipe;
```

syntax in `F#` (what is the equivilant of `+=` in `F#`). I know this is responsible for event subscription, which makes me think I should use the `Add` method in `F#` for this, however I'm not sure how. Also, what are the signatures of the `onSwipe`, `onSwipeCancelled`... functions should be. The type expected by `DidSwipeLeft` and the others is `'IEvent<EventHandler<SwipeEventArgs>,SwipeEventArgs>`

The full API is called XCardView and can be found here:

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/XCardView/true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let onSwipe = fun args -> printfn "View swiped"

DemoCardView.DidSwipeLeft.Add(onSwipe)
```

Or, simply

```
DemoCardView.DidSwipeLeft.Add(fun args -> printfn "View swiped")
```